# MYSQL Sum error

Tags: mysql, sum

I have a table like this:

```
ID | Amount | Artnr 
41 | -10    | 500N00009
40 | -10    | 500N00009
30 | -10    | 500N00009
36 | -10    | 500N00009
39 | -10    | 500N00009
52 | -1     | 500N00009
38 | -100   | 500N00009`
```

So, in Excel and calculated with an calculator the SUM of Amount would be " -151"

I use this query

`SELECT SUM(amount) AS sum_amount FROM bookings WHERE article = '500N00009' AND amount > '0'`

and it gives as result "12"

where is the problem here?

Comment: what is the data type of amount and why amount > '0' ?

Comment: amount is "decimal 10.0, and >0, because if you add something to my storage, its a positive value eg.5, and if you remove something its negative eg -1, and i want to see how many items have been removed...

Comment: it wouldn't be -151, because you check > 0 values only

Comment: ok that might be right, but why 12? it should be 0 then?

Comment: @HKK: I dare say you have other entries you don't realize you have, with `amount > 0`.

Comment: are you sure there is not positive values?

Comment: oww :( im sorry...yup..i see...

Comment: will you remove question? it zero helpful, I think...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use following query

```
SELECT SUM(amount) AS sum_amount FROM bookings WHERE article = '500N00009' AND amount<'0'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(amount) AS sum_amount
FROM bookings 
WHERE 
article = '500N00009'
AND amount <0
```

This will give sum of all -ve values